# How do i filter for answered questions?

Tags: support

I know I can look at unanswered questions, but a few times I have wondered about answered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter nothing in the search box and just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you'll see a link to the right of the *search* button. This will tell you how to do advance filtering options from tags, to scores, views and etc.

To filter for all questions that have at least one answer.

> [search term] answers:1

To filter for all questions that have an accepted answer.

> [search term] hasaccepted:yes

---

As [Aarthi♦](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search) said you can also access the page directly.

> You can also access that page directly from: raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search

Comment: You can also access that page directly from: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search